# Can't get input from user while dealing with strings in file handling

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

**I don't know how to deal with that,
**whenever I run this code, I'm unable to input strings at runtime. The compiler just skips that part.
Actually, when I remove file handling, the strings work perfectly but when I add File handling then the compiler skips the strings, and when I use **cin.ignore():** , I can enter strings at runtime but the output is all messed up.
I'm a newbie in programming and I need help.
Thank you :)****
help me in

> inputting values

```
    //ofstream to create file.
//ifstream to read data from file.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void write();
void read();
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Press 1 to write data into file" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to read data from file" << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1) {
        write();
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        read();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    
    system("pause");
}
void write() {
        string teacher, student;
cout << "Enter teacher's name: ";
getline(cin, teacher);
cout << teacher << endl;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Enter student's name: ";
getline(cin, student);
cout << student << endl;
cin.ignore();

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("F://abc.txt", ios::app);
    myfile << teacher << "...." << student << endl;
    myfile.close();

}

void read() {
    string teacher, student;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("F://abc.txt");

    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> teacher >> student;

        cout << teacher << " " << student << endl;
    }

    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Did you really write so much code, before trying to test to see if it works correctly? It's likely that there are multiple problems, which makes it much harder to figure out every one of them. It's much better to only write a few lines at a time, then test them and make sure they work correctly before writing more. That's how professional C++ developers write large applications. They don't write everything all at once, of course. This way, with only a few new lines of code at a time, if there's a problem it's just one problem, easily identified and fixed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
Sorry I just shared the whole code instead of sharing the problematic section.
so now I'm entering the code creating the error, below! Kindly check the flaw in it.

'#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
 char teacher[20], student[20];
 cout << "Enter teacher's name: ";
 cin.get(teacher, 20);
 cout << teacher << endl;
 cout << "Enter student's name: ";
 cin.get(student, 20);
 cout << student << endl;
 
 system("pause");
}
'

Comment: Going to guess your file is never opened. Use one `/`. You might also change your loop from `while (!myfile.eof()) { ... }` to `while (myfile >> teacher >> student) { ... }`.

Comment: Use `std::getline`.  Stop using `char` arrays.  Also `"F://abc.txt"` is not a valid Windows path.

Comment: Well, what is the "problematic section". Can you take the "problematic section", and turn it into a [mre], as explained in Stackoverflow's [help]? Before posting your first question to Stackoverflow did you take our [tour], read the [help], learn [ask] questions, and become familiar with Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre]?

Comment: @RetiredNinja 

The text file is created in the F drive and the student name is stored in it but I'm unable to enter the teacher's name on runtime.
And I've also used string but the same problem occurs.

Comment: @paddy
This is the correct path I think!

Comment: @paddy AFAIK, the file systems are forgiving concerning duplicated dir. separators. At least, it worked on Linux: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8a73499f8fbf39a). So, it's looking ugly and wrong but isn't necessary a critical error.

Comment: @Scheff It worked for me today on Windows 10 as well. I'm certain I have seen it fail in the past because I remember fixing it. If I was doing an assignment where I was being graded I'd do my best to make sure the little things like that were correct since it's a very low effort change.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I once noticed this and even don't remember anymore on which OS. I wouldn't rely on this, and, of course, I wouldn't tolerate this in my productive code. :-)

Comment: I've edited the question and code, please check again

Comment: @RetiredNinja Still not working :(